# Is there a way to override Android's platform attribute value at the app level?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I have a custom viewholder class that gets a color from an attribute in the android namespace in the constructor:

```
int mDefaultPrimaryColor = GetColor(context, android.R.attr.colorPrimary);

....

public static int getColor(Context context, int attr)
{
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{attr});
    int color = ta.getColor(0, 0);
    ta.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Later on the bind method eventually sets the color:

```
someTextView.setTextColor(mDefaultPrimaryColor);
```

I would like to override the android.R.attr.colorPrimary value in my app through XML without modifying Java code so that the value is different than the one being set in the SDK.

I tried to override this value in my themes.xml:

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

However, the color I am seeing in the Android emulator is not the color I have set for my_color. Is there a way to override the android.R.attr.colorPrimary with a color I defined in my app? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The theme is already set in the manifest file. Updated the code snippet to be more exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't go quite far enough to get the color code. Try this:

```
// Extract the color attribute we are interested in.
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.colorPrimary});
// From the TypedArray retrive the value we want and default if it is not found.
int defaultColor = a.getColor(0, 0xFFFFFF);
// Make sure to recycle the TypedArray.
a.recycle();
```

Now in your theme/style, you can specify something like the following:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
```

which is

```
<!-- A light Holo shade of blue. Equivalent to #ff33b5e5. -->
<color name="holo_blue_light">#ff33b5e5</color>
```

You would, of course, have to apply this color as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have showed the complete code. The part after getting the TypedArray is there. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @dividebyzero Well, that code should work. Place a debug break point in your code after picking up the color to verify whether you are getting it or not (At ` ta.recycle()` would be a good place). My guess is that you are retrieving the value you want but the code fails to apply it properly or it is being changed afterward and before it is displayed.

Comment: @dividebyzero Another thing to check is the logic in the bind method. If there is any logic there, it may be following a path you didn't anticipate. Remember that view holders are reused.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate theme with changed attribute value then pass the theme to a view passing the `ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.new_theme)` as a context.

Check the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper

**UPD**: it is surely possible to set the colorPrimary in theme as you tried. You need to add

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    ...
```

to AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I should have mentioned this but the theme is already set in the manifest so I suspect there's something else going on.